# For some given $3\times3$ matrix $A^{-1}$ and $3\times2$ matrix $B$, solve $AC=B$ for $C$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

> Let $A^{-1}$ = $\begin{pmatrix}
> 1 &2  &1 \\ 
> 0 & 3 & 1\\ 
> 4 & 1 & 2
> \end{pmatrix}$. 
>   Find matrix $C$ such that $AC = \begin{pmatrix}
> 1 &2\\ 
> 0 & 1\\ 
> 4 & 1
> \end{pmatrix}$.

How do I do this problem?
The only thing I could think of doing finding $A$, which is $(A^{-1})^{-1}$

$A = \begin{pmatrix}
5 &-3  &-1 \\ 
4 &  -2&-1 \\ 
-12 &  7& 3
\end{pmatrix}$

I know $C = 3 \times 2$, since $AC = 3 \times 2$.
So,

\begin{pmatrix}
5 &-3  &-1 \\ 
4 &  -2&-1 \\ 
-12 &  7& 3
\end{pmatrix}
times
\begin{pmatrix}
 a& b\\ 
c & d\\ 
e & f
\end{pmatrix}
is $AC$.

How do I proceed from here? This seems very long. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Multiply by $A^{-1}$ on both sides of the desired equality. What do you get on the LHS?

Comment: ohh! I get that $C = \text {matrix AC times } A^{-1}$

Comment: or I get that $C = A^{-1} \text { times matrix AC} $

Comment: Let $B$ equal $\begin{pmatrix}
1 &2\\ 
0 & 1\\ 
4 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$. You wish to find $C$ such that $AC=B$. I asked you multiply on the left by $A^{-1}$, so you get $A^{-1}(AC)=A^{-1}B$. Do you understand this? Can you proceed?

Comment: yes thanks it worked out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}
5 &-3  &-1 \\ 
4 &  -2&-1 \\ 
-12 &  7& 3
\end{pmatrix}$

Now
$$AC= \begin{pmatrix}
1 &2\\ 
0 & 1\\ 
4 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\implies C=A^{-1} \begin{pmatrix}
1 &2\\ 
0 & 1\\ 
4 & 1
\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}
5 &5\\ 
4 & 4\\ 
12 & 11
\end{pmatrix}$$